# How to sync non-system photo library to iPhone

Tags: itunes, macos, photos

The default photo library is system library. Any new library created is non-system photo library. How to sync the photos in these library into iPhone? In iTunes it seems that you can only sync the system library. Is there any app useful?

- Yosemite 10.10.3
- Photos 1.0
- iTunes 12.1.2.27
- iOS 8.3

Comment: and this is not it? https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201313

Comment: What does sync mean? Are you open to storing the secondary libraries in another cloud like flickr? How many secondary libraries are in play? Why not just place all the photos in the library that syncs via iCloud? ( I ask all these questions to illustrate some potential edits if you don't get a useful answer - See the [help] center and specifically [How to ask](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for detailed guidance.

Comment: Sync means transfer all the photos in the library to my iPhone just in one click in iTunes so that I can browse them on my iPhone. I don't want to store my photo in cloud. Thousands of photos. Thank you.

Comment: @Buscar웃 That is for the system library. I'd like to sync both system library and any other libraries.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know what is System Library? a Folder somewhere ?

Answer (score 1):

In Photos go to Preferences and you'll see an option to "Use as System Photo Library". It will then see whatever library you chose in iTunes.